# Laravel 4- How to link to another route within a for each

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to create a list of application_id s which will be routed to necessary application.The set of application_id s are coming with an array of application objects as shown in the code.I want to use the application id in my controller method too.But with my code, each application_id is not given a unique name too.

I am new to laravel and please give some way to uniquely route items within a for-each.

```
@foreach($application_set_set as $type1)
    {{Form:: open(array('url' =>'school/verifytype1','method' => 'POST' ))}}
    {{Form::submit('type1',$type1->getApplication_id())}}
    {{Form:: close()}}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're trying to print multiple forms using foreaach ? But why ?

Comment: I am trying to click on them to route to the next route with the selected value.May be it is not quite good. A drop down list would be more suitable to my task.

Comment: Yes, You need to know how to create a dropdown in foreach ?